# Loki and Dropbox

Tags: slingshot, files

It seems Dropbox is not really compatible with Loki.

Dropbox runs but the icon does not show in slingshot even when using the trick we used in Freya:
*env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity dropbox start*

Also there are no Dropbox icons nor Dropbox menu in Files !

Is it possible to fix this ?

Answer (score 5):

I recommend this script https://github.com/zant95/elementary-dropbox. Works like a charm.

Comment: why not mark it definitive?

Answer (score 1):

From the script https://github.com/zant95/elementary-dropbox, I gathered I just needed to add `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=''`

so the complete line to add in the autostart applications (Parameters => Applications => Startup)  is:

```
env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE='' dropbox start
```

And uncheck the "*startup at launch*" option, from dropbox application.

**WATCH OUT** for the single quote in the command as double quote will generate a silent error (Loki bug).

And dropbox indicator works fine !

Comment: @Japborst: please do not edit my post and create yours !

Answer (score 0):

I installed Caja Dropbox from the app store and added it to my apps at start up and then switched the slider to on.