# System Load Indicator (indicator-multiload) doesn't work correctly on Loki

Tags: wingpanel

The menu content never changes

https://youtu.be/N0d60i3j-AA

It also happens to Psensor, too.

Comment: Strange, it works for me ? How did you install ? I used: - ppa:indicator-multiload/stable-daily for indicator-multiload - ppa:sneetsher/copies for indicator-sensors lm-sensors

Comment: I installed them from apt.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [syspeek](https://launchpad.net/syspeek) but indicator menu content doesn't refresh automatically. And dropbox indicator has no menu entry..

Comment: Me, too. It is what exactly happens to the indicator-multiload and psensor.

Comment: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7555/loki-and-dropbox

Comment: @Djax, I'm also using https://github.com/zant95/elementary-dropbox but some times menu entries not shown.Thanks for comment